# openstack create and set user in an instance

Tags: openstack, provisioning

Im searching for a way to make my openstack create/set a instance with specific user that have specific password

for example i want to provision an instance that will have specific user ( lets say bobi ) who will have password ( lets say bobi123 ).

and when instance is finishing setting up, and it is running i can log from console with a user bobi and pass bobi123

is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). During instance creation your user-data is injected by the openstack metadata service (neutron) with all your required users, passwords, etc. You need to make sure that your base image has the cloud-init services enabled so they'll start during boot and can contact the metadata service.

Comment: i will check that and i will write you back with some updates after i test this :)

Comment: ok, so there is no way to make a user and passowrd to that user from Horison :/
I manage to make it work with user_data file with both methods ( cloud init and detachable drive (there is a property in server create command) ) 
And basically i need to create a new site with fields for username and password which need to be translated to file and than script should run server create command with this file :/

also retreive password does not retreive the password you enter :/ O and better crypt the password with some tool because you can see it from metadata or mounting the CD Drive :D

Comment: You can also provide the user-data in Horizon when creating an instance.

Comment: True. But the user need to write a _script_ him self on the creation of the instance :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script you could use to set default passwords and enable SSH password authentication.

```
#cloud-config
chpasswd:
 list: |
   root:stackops
   ubuntu:stackops
 expire: False
ssh_pwauth: True
```